# Cделать так, чтобы при отключении наушников ставилась пауза для музыки?

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, app, headset

Есть приложение, которое воспроизводит через интернет радио потоки. Присутствуют кнопки, чтобы останавливать проигрывание и продолжать его.

Если слушать радио в наушниках, и вынуть их, то радио продолжает играть.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при отключении наушников ставилась пауза. Я новичок в программировании, и совсем не пойму как это реализовать.

Буду очень сильно благодарен за подробный ответ на мой вопрос. Мне подсказали, что для этого есть специальное событие, о котором уведомляет система. "Поймать" его можно с помощью так называемых Broadcast Reciever'ов. Вот код, который показывает, как узнать о подключении/отключении наушников:

```
  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
  private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume(){ 
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume(); 
  }


  private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch (state) { 
          case 0: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники отключены"); break; 
          case 1: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники подключены"); break; 
          default: Log.d(TAG, "Неизвестное состояние"); 
        } 
      }
    }
  } 

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onPause(); 
  }
}
```

**Что с ним делать дальше я не совсем понял. Куда вставить и что поменять/создать?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный код описывает `MainActivity` и подключение `reciever'а`

Больше всего вас должен интересовать класс:

```
private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
  @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
      int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
      switch (state) { 
        case 0: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники отключены"); break; 
        case 1: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники подключены"); break; 
        default: Log.d(TAG, "Неизвестное состояние"); 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

а в частности строка `case 0: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники отключены"); break;`

Вставьте код, завершения проигрывания, в неё

```
case 0:
 if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.pause();
 } 
break;
```

Comment: при установке/извлечении наушников получаю правильные логи, находясь в любом из имеющихся у меня activity, как мне нужно:

D/com.online.radio.activity.HomeActivity: Наушники подключены D/com.online.radio.activity.HomeActivity: Наушники отключены ,

как дальше сделать так чтоб проигрывание завершалось при отключении?

вариант что ниже, не совсем получается сделать.,так как слово mediaPlayer подчеркивает красным...

Как и что изменить нужно??

case 0: 
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.pause();
 }
break;

Comment: @Антон, mediaPlayer это ваш плеер, через который вы проигрываете музыку. В вашем коде не приведено название переменной, так что я взял первое попавшееся.

Comment: вроде бы получилось. тогда такой вопрос:
для вывода сообщения на экран использую:
Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники отключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
и также для подключения. Как здесь же указать , чтоб проверялось, если уже подключены наушники, то не выводить каждый раз сообщение об этом. А то между активити допустим перемещаюсь , и мне постоянно прилетает сообщение, мол наушники подключены... p.s: чтото дописать туда же нужно содержащее " true и false"

Answer (score 0):

Получилось реализовать таким вот способом:

```
class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
                switch (state) {
                    case 0: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники отключены");{
                        if (HomeActivity.musicSrv.isPng()){
                            HomeActivity.musicSrv.pausePlayer();
                        }
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники отключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники подключены");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники подключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default: Log.d(TAG, "Неизвестное состояние");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Осталось для Toast сделать проверку на подключение или отсутствие наушников, чтоб не показывал каждый раз уведомление о состоянии, при открытии activity...